# API calls in electron don't maintain sessions, while postman does

Tags: python, flask, electron

When I make a call to my RESTful API (implemented using flask) to login from Electron, it doesn't maintain the session. Here's an example:

```
@app.route('/login', methods=['POST'])
def login():
    userID = request.form['userID']
    password = request.form['password']
    #login logic
    login_status = True
    print (session.get('userID'))
    if session.get('userID'):
        return jsonify({"status": "already logged in"})
    if login_status:
        session['userID'] = userID
        print (session['userID'])
        return jsonify({"status": "success"})
    else:
        return jsonify({"status": "failure"})
```

When I make two calls to the login route in Postman, it tells me that I have already been logged in. However, when I make two calls to the login route from Electron, it returns "success" twice, instead of telling me that I have already logged in. Any idea why this might be the case? Does Flask not preserve state when calls are made from Electron?

My API call from node.js in electron:

```
var formData = {
    userID: String(user_id),
    password: String(password_input)
  };
  request.post({
    url: url,
    form: formData,
  }, function optionalCallback(err, httpResponse, body) {
    if (httpResponse.statusCode != 200) {
      console.log(user_id);
      console.log(password_input);
      console.log(ip_address);
      console.log(String(ip_address + 'login'));
      return console.error('Connection failed. Incorrect credentials. Status code:', httpResponse.statusCode);
    }
    // API_IP_address = ip_address;
    console.log('Connection successful!  Server responded with:', JSON.parse(body));
  });
```